# Terraform creating user account and send password via e-mail

Tags: terraform

I want to create by terraform a user account with "Programmatic access" and "AWS Management Console access" and then send it via e-mail with a password to this user.

I can't find informations about this on terraform page. Can you help me?
I don't wan't to do this using "keybase" application.

Comment: Terraform can't send emails. You can create an app that run `terraform output` and send the information.

Comment: Thank you! You are good man! :)